# How to execute a sequence of a workflow on remote service

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

I have following scenario:
I have a client application and an agent communicating per WCF service. I have workflow containing a special composition activity "RunOnAgent", which has some children activities.

Now I want to execute the workflow on the client application. The RunOnAgent activity will execute the "sub activities worflow" on the agent and continue afterwards on the client again.

My first idea was to create an custom NativeActivity, but I'm not sure if this is the right way.

So my question is, how can I solve this problem?

Thanks for help,
Eny

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create a NativeActivity if you want it to include some other activities.